# ear module no find ${project.version}

Tags: maven, dependency-management

I have this paren't pom with dependencyManagement:

```
<dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>gpt.domini</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>gpt.ejb</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>ejb</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>gpt.logica</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>gpt.ui</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>

      </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>
```

And in my ear module i want to reference this dependencies, like that:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>gpt.domini</artifactId>
            <!--  <version>${project.version}</version>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>gpt.ejb</artifactId>
            <!--  <type>ejb</type>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>gpt.logica</artifactId>
            <!--  <version>${project.version}</version>-->
            <!--  <type>jar</type>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>gpt.ui</artifactId>
            <!--  <version>${project.version}</version>-->
            <!--  <type>war</type>-->
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

but maven tell me this error: 
Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for cat.base.gpt:gpt.ui:jar is missing.

so, why i need to specify two times the version? this haven't any sense, what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you define via the dependencyManagement

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>gpt.ui</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <type>war</type>
</dependency>
```

but in your dependencies you define the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>gpt.ui</artifactId>
    <!--  <version>${project.version}</version>-->
    <!--  <type>war</type>-->
</dependency>
```

which means there is no type defined and in maven wording means the type is assumed to be the default which is: **jar** so you need to change your dependency into this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>gpt.ui</artifactId>
    <type>war</type>
</dependency>
```